# spatie media library with cloudinary

Tags: laravel, cloudinary

I'm trying to integrate spatie media library package to use cloudinary to host and serve images..

the package didnt support cloudinary so I had to use another old package: flysystem-cloudinary

I also followed a discussion on stackoverflow where someone also battled it: [spatie-cloudinary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58977528/using-cloudinary-with-spatie-media-library-laravel-package)

I managed to upload an image to cloudinary but when I'm trying to retrieve it, I get this error:

> Declaration of App\Cloudinary\CloudinaryUrlGenerator::getTemporaryUrl(): string must be compatible with Spatie\MediaLibrary\UrlGenerator\UrlGenerator::getTemporaryUrl(DateTimeInterface $expiration, array $options = Array): string

This is my CloudinaryUrlGenerator:

```
<?php

namespace App\Cloudinary;

use Spatie\MediaLibrary\UrlGenerator\BaseUrlGenerator;

class CloudinaryUrlGenerator extends BaseUrlGenerator
{
    const HOST = 'https://res.cloudinary.com/';

/**
 * Get the url for a media item.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getUrl(): string
{
    $cloudBaseUrl = self::HOST . config('filesystems.disks.cloudinary.cloud_name') . '/';

    $options = [
        'q_auto',
    ];

    $filePathIncludingFilenameAndExtension = '/' . $this->pathGenerator->getPath($this->media) . $this->media->file_name;

    return $cloudBaseUrl . implode(',', $options) . $filePathIncludingFilenameAndExtension;
}

/**
 * Get the temp url for a media item.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTemporaryUrl(): string
{
    return $this->getUrl();
}

/**
 * Get the responsive images directory url for a media item.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getResponsiveImagesDirectoryUrl(): string
{
    return $this->getUrl();
}
}
```

I tried to play with the function definition but it didnt solve it.

Comment: What do you think could be wrong by reading the error? Especially the "must be compatible with" part?

Comment: hi @ThomasVanderVeen, thanks for replying - I tried to rewrite the function definition to be same as the spatie option:
getTemporaryUrl(DateTimeInterface $expiration, array $options): string

but it didnt work and produced the same error.

Comment: Make sure you import all the classes you need. If done correctly I think there should not be an issue. Are you sure the error is thrown because of the implementation in **your** `App\Cloudinary\CloudinaryUrlGenerator` class  (just to be sure)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it if you are using `< v7`.

Since `v7` was released, `getTemporaryUrl` has two parameters :

```php
getTemporaryUrl(DateTimeInterface $expiration, array $options = []): string;
```

You can add these parameters to your method :

```php
use DateTimeInterface;

// 

public function getTemporaryUrl(DateTimeInterface $expiration, array $options = []): string
{
    return $this->getUrl();
}
``
```

Comment: thx but I'm using V7.. I actually fixed the problem exactly like you wrote, but I have another problem.. the overwrite of images in cloudinary doesnt work... It really sucks there isn't a package for this.. Would I be better off with s3 and cloudfront/flare? I think the cloudinary package is the problematic